# Terminal Server CPU usage at 100%

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, terminal-server

I'm running a terminal server with around 50-60 users,and every so often the server will go from > 40% usage to 100%. I took a closer look an it seems every time this happens, a different user or two seem to be caught in a loop and end up using < 30% where the rest of the users only use a maximum of 5%.

The company behind the software we use clame it's due to the servers inadequate hardware (It's a VM system running on a dual - quad core setup) which to me sounds like BS!

I'm fairly new to this level of IT so if I misspoke I apologize. I have no way to prove it but I believe adding more raw hardware power wont do me any good as this to me seems like a bug in their software, and it will suck up as much ( or little) CPU as it's given.

The VM in question has 4 vCPU cores and 12 GB RAM available, and is running Windows Server 2008, 64-bit

Thanks in advance for your help!

Note: I have the same question posted on SO, but was pointed in this direction so just in case, here is a link to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276602/termserver-cpu-at-100

Comment: Is this Windows terminal server? Or some other? There's not really a lot of information here...

Comment: Im sorry, It's a windows 2008 64bit server.

and thank you for your quick response!

Comment: You say that it's a VM running on a physical 2x 4-core server. How many vCPUs are assigned to the VM? How much RAM? What application is in use that eats up the CPU?

Comment: 4 cores are assigned to this VM, with 12GB or ram. The software we use is what eats up the CPU usage.

Comment: And what software is this? What does it do? Does it tie into SQL somewhere? What are the requirements for the software?

Comment: The Software is office practicum. It's an EMR made for pediatrics.

Comment: Might want to mention VMWare or HyperV or something else as processors are handled differently in each.  Are you using Windows Terminal Services or Citrix or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your goal, you might want to use threadlocker and lock the program that is causing high CPU usage to a single or multiple cores other than the first core.  That will at least keep a core or two free so your machine doesn't lock and the 'bug' or whatever is going on with that program can just have fun doing what it does on it's own core.

Info with download link on the bottom:
http://andrewmorgan.ie/2012/05/15/introducing-threadlocker-a-community-tool-for-granular-control-of-processes/

Comment: It's okay to link to products, but the link on the file-sharing service looked quite spammy/malwareish, so I've removed it.  Also, please disclose whether or not you have any kind of affiliation with the product vendor.  Thanks!

Comment: @KatherineVillyard I understand that. I don't like their site either.  I am not affiliated with them at all.